# Twitter API - Update Profile

Tags: php, twitter

Im looking at the Twitter API: http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-account%C2%A0update_profile

I want to update my profile via PHP.

Specifically my location: San Francisco, CA

Im not looking for anything fancy, just a way of calling the XML, checking its contents, then writing in a new value if appropriate.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function updateProfile($name = null, $email = null, $url = null, $location = null, $description = null)
    {
        // validate parameters
        if($name === null && $email === null && $url === null && $location === null && $description === null) throw new TwitterException('Specify at least one parameter.');
        if($name !== null && strlen($name) > 40) throw new TwitterException('Maximum 40 characters allowed for name.');
        if($email !== null && strlen($email) > 40) throw new TwitterException('Maximum 40 characters allowed for email.');
        if($url !== null && strlen($url) > 100) throw new TwitterException('Maximum 100 characters allowed for url.');
        if($location !== null && strlen($location) > 30) throw new TwitterException('Maximum 30 characters allowed for location.');
        if($description !== null && strlen($description) > 160) throw new TwitterException('Maximum 160 characters allowed for description.');

        // build parameters
        if($name !== null) $aParameters['name'] = (string) $name;
        if($email !== null) $aParameters['email'] = (string) $email;
        if($url !== null) $aParameters['url'] = (string) $url;
        if($location !== null) $aParameters['location'] = (string) $location;
        if($description !== null) $aParameters['description'] = (string) $description;

        // make the call
        $response = $this->doCall('account/update_profile.xml', $aParameters, true);

        // convert into xml-object
        $xml = @simplexml_load_string($response);

        // validate
        if($xml == false) throw new TwitterException('invalid body');

        // return
        return (array) $this->userXMLToArray($xml, true);
    }
```

Comment: Could you give me an idea of how i would use this?

Comment: ok first you need a twitter library if you want i can give you my twitter library http://www.code.google.com/p/twitter-boot you will find it http://code.google.com/p/twitter-boot/source/browse/trunk/twitter-bot/inc/twitter/twitter.php here include it in your script look at the twitter-bot ihave written you will find many examples

Comment: I imagine your were voted down for your comments below, however thank you for your assitance.

Comment: you are welcome if you have questions for the bot fom google code which i wrote you can mail me wyde16@gmail.com

Answer (score -2):

```
curl -u user:password -d "location=San Francisco, CA" http://twitter.com/account/update_profile.xml
```

Comment: However come July this year Twitter will be phasing this simple Authorization out, and you'll need to use OAuth...

Comment: are all peoples drunk the guy above asked how to do it using php